# Exclude certain numbers from a range of random numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random

I am trying to generate random numbers.
I do it like this:

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
        return  Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

I'm trying to get a number in the range from 0 to 100. Excluding the range from 40 to 60 from the answer
How to do it?

Comment: Do not understand what do you want to do

Comment: @flyingfox I'm trying to get a number in the range from 0 to 100. Excluding the range from 40 to 60 from the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate a random number that spans the length of the inclusive range, then readjust that to either be at the first min number or the second min number.

Note that this algorithm gives numbers on the interval `[min1, max1) U [min2, max2)`, which is also `min1 <= num < max1 OR min2 <= num < max2`.

```js
function getRandom(min1, max1, min2, max2) {
  const range = (max1 - min1) + (max2 - min2);
  const initial = range * Math.random();
  if (initial < max1 - min1) {
    return initial + min1;
  } else {
    return initial + min2 - (max1 - min1);
  }
}

console.log(getRandom(0, 40, 60, 100));
```